# Can I use same GTM tag to fire for multiple GA accounts?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working on one project which needs to fire same GTM tag to for two different GA account is this possible? or should I have duplicate all the same tags for two GA accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to fire multiple properties in one tag. However I can think of two possible workarounds.

(**Updated**: The same questions came up [on the GTM forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/ZSJqjzw4uKc;context-place=topicsearchin/tag-manager/multipe$20ga) and naturally Simo Ahava had a solution).

One would be to create the tracker object [manually in a custom html tag](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/access-the-tracker-object-in-your-page-view-tag/) (the actual pageviews happen still via Ga tag templates). This would allow you to use [Google Analytics plugins](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/using-plugins) and there are plugins (e.g. [here](https://www.thyngster.com/universal-analytics-plugin-dual-tracking/) or [here](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/double-tracking-in-ga-part-1/)) that send hits to multiple properties.

The other workaround is to use a feature called tag sequencing. This has the advantage that you do it with "pure" GTM instead of GA plugins. I will first show the steps and explain what happens later.

**The Setup**

First you need to set up your tracking id as a variable of the datalayer type. As default value you set your first tracking id:

[image]

Next you create a custom html tag that will later set the second tracker id. This also sets a custom event necessary to fire the second tracker. Note that there are no triggers attached to this tag, and that it is set to "fire only once per page" (the last thing is very important! You can set this in Advanced Settings -> Tag firing options).

[image]

Then you create a trigger that uses the custom event from the previous step:

[image]

Now comes the magic with the GA tag. You use the variable for the tracking id that you have created earlier. Then you go to "Advanced Settings", expand the "Tag Sequencing" options and check the mark before "fire a tag after  fires". You select the custom html tag from above (named set2ndId in my example). Then you attach a pageview trigger and the custom event trigger (called 2ndTracker in my example).

[image]

**The sequence**

1. GTM is loaded and evaluates the tracker id from the default value of the datalayer variable
2. The pageview trigger fires the GA tag
3. The tag sequencing setting fires the custom html tag that sets the datalayer variables for event and  tracking ind
4. Since we have an event the datalayer is re-evaluated, and the new value with the second tracker id from the custom html tag is set
5. The custom event trigger fires the GA tag with the second tracker id
6. Since the custom html tag was set to "fire once per page" it is not fired again (else you would end up in a loop)

A word of caution: This is somewhat clever, even if I say so myself, but at the moment it is a bit "proof of concept". I use it without problems for pageview tracking, but I'm still working the kinks out for event tracking etc, so you have to decide for yourself if this is useful for you.

But at least it answers your question: yes, it is possible to send to multiple properties without duplicating the GA tags, but it takes some additional setup so you have to decide if this actually saves you work.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is fine to fire multiple GA properties in single GTM.

Maybe this tutorial will help you:
http://www.kristaseiden.com/step-by-step-adding-a-second-ga-property-via-google-tag-manager/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Matus it is really helpful, but I am wondering is this possible without duplication of tags.

Comment: No problem, I am happy it helps. And no it is not possible to have multiple Tracking IDs in a single tag.